# How to make tinymce paste in plain text by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Googled it thousands of times, No one gives a complete solution of how to make Tinymce paste in plain text by default and strip out any formatting without clicking the "paste as text" button.

Any Ideas of how to implement that? or how to enable the "paste as text" button automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**EDIT:** this solution is for version 3.x, for 4.x version read the answer from @Paulo Neves

The problem is that Paste plugin automatically resets plain text paste on every paste. So all we need to do - set it back. The following code should help.

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
oninit : "setPlainText",
plugins : "paste"

....
});
```

The definition of  setPlainText

```
 function setPlainText() {
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('elm1');

        ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;  

        //adding handlers crossbrowser
        if (tinymce.isOpera || /Firefox\/2/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            ed.onKeyDown.add(function (ed, e) {
                if (((tinymce.isMac ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey) && e.keyCode == 86) || (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 45))
                    ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
            });
        } else {            
            ed.onPaste.addToTop(function (ed, e) {
                ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
            });
        }
    }
```

So now it always will be plain.

Comment: I thtink it's becouse of absent paste plugin
I've created working example - take a look
http://92.248.232.12/tinymce/examples/simple.html

tinyMCE.init({
...
oninit : "setPlainText",
plugins : "paste"
....
});

Comment: Great answer, although I've found I get JS errors relating to the definition of "ed". This was simple to fix by just removing the tinyMCE.get("elm1") line and putting ed as the first parameter of the setPlainText method: e.g. "function setPlainText(ed) { ...".

Comment: In later versions of tinymce, some options were added to take care of this. `paste_text_sticky_default: true` and `paste_text_sticky: true` in your config should do the trick. (I'm using 3.5.0.1)

Comment: @er-v any suggestions on how to persist the tinyMCE formatted string using a form : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247900/save-formatted-text-to-database-and-retrieve-it-back-as-is-like-a-formatted-st

Comment: That ` /Firefox\/2/.test(navigator.userAgent)` actually makes a serious inconsistency, since it thinks Firefox 26 is Firefox 2, and adds clean-up functionality to Ctrl+V but not paste from the menu. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26540#ticket

Comment: Worked perfectly here on tinyMCE 3.x!

Comment: Just tried `.init({ plugins: ["paste"], paste_as_text: true })`, and it works like a charm with TinyMCE 4.1, without the need of an additional function.

Comment: maybe a silly question but this work with the default WP editor or do you need to install the plugin?

Comment: This no longer works. Use http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:paste to see the list of settings regarding paste.

Answer (score 174):

For the tinyMCE 3X or 4X things have change a little.
now you can do this and it works fine.

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "paste",
    paste_as_text: true
});
```

Comment: Yes,the other approaches did not work but this does.

Comment: @Tim The approach shown in the answer of this question is specific TinyMCE 3.x. If you're using TinyMCE 4 or bigger, the approach in this answer will do.

Comment: There is a plugin or option for just about anything in TinyMCE.. no wonder it is the best!

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but this actually mean that I've to remember to edit the configuration file every time the plugins got updated?

Answer (score 87):

I have solved this problem with this code

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
plugins : "paste",
paste_text_sticky : true,
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
      ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
    });
  }
....
})
```

Comment: For what it worth, I think your solution is better than the selected answer.

Comment: @Dariusz Lyson , any suggestions on how to persist the tinyMCE formatted string using a form ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247900/save-formatted-text-to-database-and-retrieve-it-back-as-is-like-a-formatted-st

Comment: I get a javascript error, that the `onInit` property of `ed` is undefined. `Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: for TinyMCE v.4. this version activates button 'pastetext' by default.

Answer (score 38):

Just ran into this one myself and discovered that as of TinyMCE 3.4.2 you can simply:

```
paste_text_sticky: true,
paste_text_sticky_default: true
```

...which was nice.

Comment: +1 for these config options, do not forget to add the paste plugin to the plugin array !

Comment: The editor is still allowing pasting of other-than-plain-text when I use this approach.

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way would be this:

```
tinymce.init({
   ...
   paste_as_text: true,
   plugins: "paste",
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to use:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
```

instead of:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('elm1');
```

Comment: I agree, I was able to make my script work using activeEditor instead of get('elm1'), I also posted in my answer your code + code accepted as answer and it is working great

Comment: This is a comment directed towards er-v's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2727189/369450). This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, TinyMCE has improved this by implementing it as a default option in the paste plugin.
More info: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

However, it's still not perfect.
So here is a script that also trips off all HTML:

```
// Paste
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_remove_spans: true,
        paste_remove_styles: true,
        paste_retain_style_properties: false,

        paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) 
        {    // Replace <div> with <p>
            o.content = o.content.replace(/<div>/gi, "<p>");    
            o.content = o.content.replace(/<\/div>/gi, "</p>");
            o.content = o.content.replace(/<\r\n/gi, "\n");
            o.content = o.content.replace(/<\n\n/gi, "\n");
            o.content = o.content.replace(/<\n\n/gi, "\n");

            // Replace empty styles
            o.content = o.content.replace(/<style><\/style>/gi, "");    

            o.wordContent = true;            
        },

        paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) 
        {    //console.log(o.node.innerHTML);
            var ed = pl.editor, dom = ed.dom;

            // Remove all tags which are not <p> or <br>
            tinymce.each(dom.select('*', o.node), function(el) 
            {    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() != "p" && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != "br") 
                {    dom.remove(el, 1); // 1 = KeepChildren
                    console.log(el.tagName);
                }
                dom.setAttrib(el, 'style', '');
            });

        },
```

Source:
http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=60121#p60121

Answer (score 1):

### Without plug-in: Listen to paste event, get clipboard data

If you cannot use or do not want to use a plug-in for whatever reason, you can create your own "paste as plain text" callback function like so:

```
tinyMCE.init({

    // ...,

    setup: function (editor) {

        // Listen for paste event, add "Paste as plain text" callback
        editor.onPaste.add(function (editor, e) {

            // Prevent default paste behavior
            e.preventDefault();

            // Check for clipboard data in various places for cross-browser compatibility.
            // Get that data as text.
            var content = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');

            // Let TinyMCE do the heavy lifting for inserting that content into the editor.
            editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);
        });
    }
});
```

*Note: This was created for TinyMCE 3.5.x. Compatibility may vary by version.*

Comment: Excellent solution for 3.x - none of the other replies was working in my case

Answer (score 1):

if you use a .yml file, add the plugin `paste` and `paste_as_text: true`

```
default:
  plugins:
    - paste
  paste_as_text: true
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is possible, since "paste as plaintext" actually performs cleanup on the text before it adds it to the window. If you just paste data into the window, no operations can be done. (Unless you hooked into the `onChange` or something), but they you might end up fixing code that had already been pasted and thus, 'double fixing' it.

Answer (score -1):

I did as follows:

```
var pastePlainText = function() {
    // No need to pass in an ID, instead fetch the first tinyMCE instance
    var ed = tinyMCE.get(0); 
    ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;  

    //adding handlers crossbrowser
    if (tinymce.isOpera || /Firefox\/2/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        ed.onKeyDown.add(function (ed, e) {
            if (((tinymce.isMac ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey) && e.keyCode == 86) || (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 45))
                ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
        });
    } else {            
        ed.onPaste.addToTop(function (ed, e) {
            ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
        });
    }
};
```

And then:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // ...
    plugins: "paste",
    oninit: pastePlainText // Note, without "
    // ...
})
```