# tinyMCE Removing MS Word tags

Tags: ms-word, tinymce, copy-paste

I am using tinymce Version: 3.3.7 and when I go to paste "as plain text" from tinymce, I still get mso tags. Is it possible to have these removed by some setting in tinyMCE or do I need to strip the tags with php?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not definetly sure what you want, but i guess you are trying to copy text from Word into tinymce. In order to get rid of all not wanted tags and other things like textdecoration you need to use the paste **[plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/paste)**. Use this settings for your init function:

```
plugins : "paste,...",
paste_use_dialog : false,
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
paste_convert_headers_to_strong : false,
paste_strip_class_attributes : "all",
paste_remove_spans : true,
paste_remove_styles : true,
paste_retain_style_properties : "",
```

You may also use `paste_preprocess` and/or `paste_postprocess` setting to perform javascript action on the pasted code.

Answer (score 8):

source: [How to make tinymce paste in plain text by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695731/how-to-make-tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default/3582651#3582651)

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // ...
    plugins : "paste",
    paste_text_sticky : true,
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
            ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
        });
    }
    // ...
});
```