# How to get rid of <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-GB"> after posting variables from a form

Tags: php, html, forms, character-encoding

I am working on an automation using PHP.

I have a newsletter that get sent every week and instead of editing it in an annoying CMS, I decided to use automation and create a form that gets the variables and posts them to an HTML template.

For some reason one of the fields echos this: `<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-GB">` before a text, and I am suspecting that it's because it contains chars that aren't supported, but not sure.. (in that case, is there an easy way to change the chars to supported ones?

What is the reason getting this? 
How do I resolve this problem?

EDIT:

Ok, so the problem is because text I copy is from a Word Doc, and that's what's getting me these unrelevant tags.

I want  tags, I want  tags, ect. I just don't want the tags mentioned.

I hope this is more clear now..

Comment: The reason is generating html code with Microsoft Word.

Comment: ohhh.... 
Yes I copy-paste to a tool called tinymce (www.tinymce.com) and I copy the texts from word :X 
Any alternate solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tinyMCE Removing MS Word tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790318/tinymce-removing-ms-word-tags)

Comment: @chris85 hmm, well, I want everything except of these tags... 
I want spans, a tags, ect...

Comment: Can you not modify the tinymce configuration? This is going to be hard to do after the fact (after form submission). It would be much easier to tell tinymce not to use those elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strip_tags() to clean your strings

```
$string = strip_tags($string, '<a><b><br><div><em><i><li><table><td><tr><span><sub><sup><strong><u><ul>');
```

and so on

PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Edited to include alowed tags parameter (sample)

Comment: OP only wants to remove MS tags. Strip_tags can't do that (or not easily).