# Tinymce paste includes styles

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have a tinymce form and it's working for the most part, but when I copy something from either the internet or a word processor and try and paste it in, the inline styles stay with it.

I have tried to solve this a few ways already, but have had no luck. It seems like this style tag is haunting me!

I would just remove the style tag altogether, and I did try this, but when I do that nullifies the styles you can add in the tinymce, such as text align...and I don't really want to do that.

This is what I have at the moment, you can see I was trying to remove the styles on paste, but it's just not working. Some help would be much appreciated!

```
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "exact",
elements : "wStory",
plugins : "paste",
theme: "advanced",
width: "80em",
height: "700px",
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
paste_remove_styles: true,
paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
paste_strip_class_attributes: true,
theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,hr,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,outdent, indent,|,cleanup,|,forecolor, |,undo,redo,|,link, unlink",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"center",
theme_advanced_resizing:false,
width:"100%",height:"700px",
invalid_elements: "span, div",
theme_advanced_path:false,
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
    ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
});
},
```

});

Comment: CKeditor (an alternative to TinyMCE) has a "paste plain" button. I think there may be a similar plugin available for TinyMCE. The easiest short-term solution would be to paste into a plain-text editor like Notepad, then copy from there.

Comment: I know, but I'm building a website for people who won't do that, that's why I'm trying to use tinymce. I'm trying to idiot proof my site. They won't know how to use a paste plain button, and I don't like how these pasted style tags brake my css.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695731/how-to-make-tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default

Comment: Re: idiot-proofing your site - The idiots will find a way! :) But this is a noble intention, and certainly pasting without styles by default is a good start. I believe the above link should solve it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortuitly, I already tried every one of those suggestions, and not one of them worked. And yes, the idiots will find a way, but I have to make it harder don't I? :)

Comment: Hmm, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3582651/560114) is the same technique used in [this Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default/), so it must work at least for TinyMCE version 3. Perhaps it doesn't work for version 4.

Comment: I don't think it does. I did some digging and finally did find an answer that finally worked after much tweaking! I swear sometimes these plug ins are more trouble than they're worth! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some odd reason, nothing I did work in the latest tinymce. I hope this helps someone else who runs into this

```
  cleanup_on_startup : true,
  fix_list_elements : false,
  fix_nesting : false,
  fix_table_elements : false,
  paste_use_dialog : true,
  paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
```

I had to paste these in the init function. This allows for it to post plain text and then when the user places styles like centering it adds a paragraph tags around the specified text

Answer (score 0):

```
init={{
  menubar: false,
  plugins: "lists advlist paste",
  toolbar: "bullist numlist",
  contenteditable: edit,
  entity_encoding: "raw",
  paste_webkit_styles: "none",
  paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
}}
```

it removes styles when copy paste.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.