# Force plain text paste

Tags: wordpress, paste, tinymce-4

WP 3.9.1
TinyMCE 4.x

I'm using wp_editor() in the frontend of my website. The problem is that when a user pastes some content with styles(bold, color ...) it appears in the tinyMCE4 editor.

How can I prevent styles from being pasted? I just want the text to be pasted.

Here is the code:

First, the tiny_mce_before_init filter:

```
function mytheme_job_tinymce_settings( $in ) {

    $in['remove_linebreaks'] = true;
    $in['gecko_spellcheck'] = false;
    $in['keep_styles'] = false;
    $in['accessibility_focus'] = true;
    $in['tabfocus_elements'] = 'major-publishing-actions';
    $in['media_strict'] = false;
    $in['paste_remove_styles'] = true;
    $in['paste_remove_spans'] = true;
    $in['paste_strip_class_attributes'] = 'all';
    $in['paste_text_use_dialog'] = false;
    $in['wpeditimage_disable_captions'] = true;
    $in['plugins'] = 'tabfocus,paste';
    $in['wpautop'] = false;
    $in['apply_source_formatting'] = false;
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,hr,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,undo,redo ';
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar3'] = '';
    $in['toolbar4'] = '';

    return $in;

}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mytheme_job_tinymce_settings' );
```

Then wp_editor() in frontend (page template):

```
wp_editor( stripslashes( $profile ) , 'profile', array(
    'textarea_name'    => 'profile',
    'textarea_rows'    => 12,
    'media_buttons'    => false,
    'teeny'            => false,
    'editor_css'       => '<style>.mce-path { display: none !important; } </style>',
    'tinymce'          => array(
        'content_css' => MYTHEME_URI . '/assets/css/editor-styles.css'
    ),
    'quicktags'        => false,
    'dfw'              => false,
    'drag_drop_upload' => false
) );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17421926/1109380:

```
function tinymce_paste_as_text( $init ) {
    $init['paste_as_text'] = true;

    // omit the pastetext button so that the user can't change it manually, current toolbar2 content as of 4.1.1 is "formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help"
    $init["toolbar2"] = "formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help";

    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_paste_as_text');
```

Comment: It doesn't FORCE it just set `paste_as_text` as default option, but user can change it later.

Comment: True that. But by omitting the `pastetext` button in the toolbars removes the ability for the user to change it. For example, change the current toolbar:

    `$init["toolbar2"] = "formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help";`


to


    `$init["toolbar2"] = "formatselect,underline,alignjustify,forecolor,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help";`

Comment: Added the above to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the user to paste without styles. I've done some adjusting from the Codex:

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['remove_linebreaks'] = false;
    $in['gecko_spellcheck'] = false;
    $in['keep_styles'] = false;
    $in['accessibility_focus'] = true;
    $in['tabfocus_elements'] = 'major-publishing-actions';
    $in['media_strict'] = false;
    $in['paste_remove_styles'] = true;
    $in['paste_remove_spans'] = true;
    $in['paste_strip_class_attributes'] = 'none';
    $in['paste_text_use_dialog'] = true; // this is the one you REALLY want! 
    $in['wpeditimage_disable_captions'] = true;
    $in['plugins'] = 'tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpfullscreen';
    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/editor-style.css";
    $in['wpautop'] = true;
    $in['apply_source_formatting'] = false;
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'spellchecker,wp_fullscreen ';
    $in['toolbar2'] = 'pastetext,removeformat,charmap,undo,redo,wp_help ';
    $in['toolbar3'] = '';
    $in['toolbar4'] = '';
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

Untested, but you can see the defaults here: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE

Comment: First, it removes styles on paste, it removes spans, it forces the dialog box (to clear styles) when pasting, and the toolbar is limited. You could also put this in an `if` statement to only apply to a certain user group.

Comment: Looks strange because it's not working, I've searched for two days on the web, no success. I really don't know what to do

Comment: Might want to double check ` /wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` to make sure they are current with MCE4.

Comment: Yes, it is, tinyMCE 4

Comment: I mean checking your functions against that php file.