# TinyMCE Rich Text Editor - Paste content without source styles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

I am using Tiny MCE RTE.
I want to know if there is any property to **Restrict** the formatting when I copy paste some content from any source.

For example, the default font set for the rich text editor is "Verdana". I am copy pasting some content from some source/document which has different styles. But when I paste that content into the rich text editor, I want to retain default font of the rich text editor.

Is this possible?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the answer to a similar question here: [How to make tinymce paste in plain text by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695731/how-to-make-tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default) and 
looking at the `[paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste]` option documented officially here http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:paste.