# tinyMCE remove all formats from the current cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I'm using tinyMCE 4 custom editor. I have use custom button for Text Bold, Font Size and Font Style by execCommand Like

```
$("#font_width").on('click', function (e) {
   tinyMCE.execCommand('Bold');
});
```

Now I want to remove all command or format by pressing Single time Enter key. 
When will pressing Enter Key within 10 millisecond then cursor will go to new line.

I'm tried by using this code

```
editor.on('keydown', function(event) {
            onKeyEvent(event);
        });
        var enterNo = 0;
        function onKeyEvent(evt){
            var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
            if ( keyCode == 13 ){
                enterNo++;
                if(enterNo==1) {
                    // $("#doc_content").remove();
                    if (typeof tinyMCE != 'undefined') {
                        // Delete all formating by textaria ID
                        // tinyMCE.DOM.remove('doc_content');
                        // This command works on only selected text
                        tinyMCE.execCommand('RemoveFormat');
                        evt.preventDefault();
                    }


                }else{
                    // alert("Press Enter 2 time");
                    setTimeout(init,10);
                    enterNo = 0;
                }                        
            }                    
        }
```

Comment: My demo link is here
https://keipro.dhaka10.dev.jacos.jp/

Comment: What's problem with your code?

Comment: You can see this link. Hope it'll solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695731/how-to-make-tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default

Comment: I can't remove Formatting my current cursor