# Add style to text after using paste_as_text in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Using TinyMCE 4 I have configured the `paste_as_text` option for the `paste` plugin as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695731/how-to-make-tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default).

It works as expected, for instance this:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1 dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 20pt; margin-bottom: 6pt;"><span style="font-size: 20pt; font-family: Arial; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Requirements</span></h1>
<h3 dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 16pt; margin-bottom: 4pt;"><span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Arial; color: #434343; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Nav Bar/Header</span></h3>
<ul style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;">
<li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;">
<p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-size: 11pt; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Change EAT | DRINK to DISCOVER but keep this as the existing dropdown everywhere</span></p>
</li>
<li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;">
<p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-size: 11pt; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Change WATCH | READ to WATCH but keep this as the existing dropdown everywhere</span></p>
</li>
<li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Arial; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;">
<p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-size: 11pt; color: #000000; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Keep EXPERIENCE as the existing dropdown everywhere</span></p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Turns into:

```
<p>Requirements<br />Nav Bar/Header<br />Change EAT | DRINK to DISCOVER but keep this as the existing dropdown everywhere<br />Change WATCH | READ to WATCH but keep this as the existing dropdown everywhere<br />Keep EXPERIENCE as the existing dropdown everywhere</p>
```

But since all the lines are inside a single `<p>` when I try to style the first line, for example changing it to `Heading 1`, all the text gets formatted to that.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really avoid this based on the fact that you are choosing to Paste As Text.

Paste As Text is going to remove all the HMTL tags and return just "text" as the feature's name would imply.

When you then do something like format something to a Heading 1 TinyMCE is taking the block in which your cursor is located and turning that block to an `<h1>`.

This working as designed.

If you only want a portion of the content to be turned into a Heading it needs to be in its own block first.  Typically, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> starts a new block (paragraph) in TinyMCE so doing that before and after the text you want would move it to its own block.

Comment: Right, but can't it be configured to use multiples `<p>` instead of `<br/>`? Maybe something on the processing settings

Comment: It you wanted multiple P tags I would just not use `paste_as_text`.  The original HTML you reference is already in multiple paragraphs.  If you continue to use `paste_as_text` you could process the content before its inserted into the editor and convert the content in any way you want including transforming the text between each `<br>` into paragraphs.

Comment: I want to remove all styling but keep different paragraphs so the users can easily set new formatting. I guess I will look into other ways of doing this.

Comment: The API would allow you to process the content upon paste but before its been inserted into the editor.  

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_postprocess

With that hook you could strip all the attributes but maintain the semantic elements.