# TinyMCE Paste as text (unformatted text) by default

Tags: tinymce

I'd like to have the paste as text (paste as unformatted text) as a default in the visual editor to help prevent client/users from pasting from word etc with embeded code etc.

I do already have the button there so wondering how I could accomplish this in my theme functions.php? Ideally after it's set as default, the button is also removed from the visual editor.

I tried looking though other forum posts and tinyMCE documents, I do find it a bit confusing where I need to add this as i'm most used to doing so in functions doc and not via javascript. I was able to get the table plugin added by adding the script downloaded from TinyMCE and then the function to call in functions.php, just can't figure this one out.

I had looked at this answer from 13 years ago ([How to make tinymce paste in plain text by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695731/how-to-make-tinymce-paste-in-plain-text-by-default)) but not sure if it's still relevent and still not sure where to even put the code. Thank in advance.